# Error from ggplot2 plotting date data -- missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I'm trying to plot some grades I'm pulling from an external source.  The date format comes in looking like this:

```
2011-08-23T17:07:05
```

So I parse it with `strptime(date, "%FT%X")` and get a `POSIXlt`.  I end up with a complete data frame that looks like this:

```
                  date    subject  grade
1  2011-08-23 17:07:05 AP Biology  95.83
2  2011-08-24 17:07:03 AP Biology  95.83
3  2011-08-25 17:08:27 AP Biology  95.83
4  2011-08-17 17:05:54 US History 157.14
5  2011-08-18 17:05:24 US History 157.14
6  2011-08-19 17:05:35 US History 157.14
7  2011-08-22 17:06:25 US History 157.14
8  2011-08-23 17:07:05 US History 157.14
9  2011-08-24 17:07:03 US History 157.14
10 2011-08-25 17:08:27 US History 157.14
11 2011-08-19 17:05:35   Yearbook   0.00
12 2011-08-22 17:06:25   Yearbook   0.00
13 2011-08-23 17:07:05   Yearbook 100.00
14 2011-08-24 17:07:03   Yearbook 100.00
15 2011-08-25 17:08:27   Yearbook 100.00
```

With the following structure:

```
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date   : POSIXlt, format: "2011-08-23 17:07:05" "2011-08-24 17:07:03" ...
 $ subject: Factor w/ 3 levels "AP Biology","US History",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ grade  : num  95.8 95.8 95.8 157.1 157.1 ...
```

When I try to plot this data:

```
> ggplot(data=grades, aes(date, grade, factor=subject)) + geom_line()
Error in if (length(range) == 1 || diff(range) == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  I narrowed it down to the date handling by doing this:

```
ggplot(data=grades,
       aes(seq(length(grades[,1])),
           grade, color=subject)) + geom_line()
```

... but how do I do the date handling correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only times of class `POSIXct` are supported in ggplot2. Class `POSIXct` represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC timezone) as a numeric vector. Class `POSIXlt` is a named list of vectors representing nine elements (`sec`, `min`, `hour`, etc.).

You can use the following:

```
grades$date <- as.POSIXct(grades$date)
```

Comment: Heh, you posted almost the same stuff at almost the same time I did.  I thank you much for your effort, though.  :)

Comment: +1 For explaining this so clearly.  It's the first time that I understand the difference.  If only it was this clear in the help files!  (And perhaps it is, I simply haven't found it yet.)

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured this out.  The difference is in understanding `POSIXct` vs. `POSIXlt`.  `POSIXlt` is the calendar time in parts.  `POSIXct` is the number of seconds since the epoch.  `strptime` returns a `POSIXct

In order to use this data, I need to convert the timestamps:

```
grades$date <- as.POSIXct(grades$date)
```